# Collatz conjecture. Find the smallest a_k

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function, that will return the smallest a_k, such that a_k equal to one. I wrote this code:

```
Function Collatz(N As Integer) As Integer

    If N Mod 2 = 0 Then
        F = N / 2
    Else
        F = (3 * N) + 1
    End If

    Collatz = F

End Function



Function Find(N As Integer) As Integer
 k = 0
 Do While N <> 1
    N = Collatz(N): k = k + 1
    If k > 10000000000# Then Exit Do
 Loop

End Function
```

Function Collatz works fine, but function Find always returns zero. How can I improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to return the result.

Find = k

Comment: Good answer! On top of that, there is a risk that Excel will follow the native `Find` function instead of Pawel's `Find` function; I'd recommend changing the name to something more unique, e.g. `FindN`.

Comment: @JustynaMK since it's `Range.Find` (i.e. `Find` is a method of `Range`, not a function), there's not this issue, but I still agree with you in choosing a more appropriate name.